# Yii2 Login Authenticate without password

Tags: php, api, yii, yii2

I am working on project that will use API of another application. So I won't validate password on my app, will do this via API request. I don't want to store users` passwords in db. Just check password by API.

How can I authenticate a user without login credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login & Session in Yii 2 is managed by [`\yii\web\User`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) class
This class is accessible in the application life cycle via the [`\Yii::$app->user`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-application-components.html#core-application-components) property.

On successful authentication using your third-party provider you use the [`login()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login()-detail) function using `Yii::$app->user->login($identity)`

`$identity` should be an object of `[IdentityInterface][4]` usually the User ActiveRecord model implementing this interface

Refer to the [guide documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html) on Authentication for full understanding on how authentication works in Yii2

Comment: So I will check if user`s credentials are valid or not with API, and if valid I will find user_id from database with given email and how use Yii::$app->user->login($identity) ?

Comment: `$identity` could be `User::findOne($user_id)` (if you implement IdentityInterface in User),

Answer (score 0):

In our app we are using a field **auth_key** related to a User Model and then we go to this link, find a user in database by this **auth_key** and make a login (or not if it is not found in database )

```
public actionAuthLogin($auth_key){
  if(($user = User::findOne(['auth_key' => $auth_key])) 
        && \Yii:$app->user->login($user)){
     return $this->goHome();
  } else {

     throw new NotFoundHttpException()
  }

}
```

then

```
/controller/auth-login?auth_key=should_be_in_database_ahsgdashdajsdg123mkasd
```